# How to change the color of a specific JButton

Tags: java

I'm very aware on how to do it if you have just one button, but for a Computer Science project I am making a Keno game GUI. To make the JButtons I made a for loop like so:

```
for(int i=1 ; i <= 80; i++)
    {
    num.add(1) ;
    btn = new JButton(String.valueOf(i)) ;
    btn.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    btn.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
    btn.setActionCommand(String.valueOf(i));
    btn.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler());
    panel.add(btn);
    }

public class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
 //Button Code if I click one button it goes here. I have set ID's via     ActionCommand

}

}
```

https://i.gyazo.com/637f74422de5f4bf6e52155dcdfbd482.png [JButton Output]

So what I wanted to do, was for when I clicked a specific number, it turn RED so it would indicate that it's been clicked. To do this, would I have to define EACH button? Or can I somehow adjust just one button this way! Any information would be greatly appreciated!

- Zachary Smith

Comment: Can you post code for `ButtonHandler`?

Comment: Nothing that should change anything but I added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to turn red after you've clicked (and stay red), you can just add that to the ButtonHandler

```
public class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        JButton b = (JButton)event.getSource();
        b.setBackground(Color.RED);
    }

     //Button Code if I click one button it goes here. I have set ID's via     ActionCommand
}
```